# Is there a way to step out of a java stream if an item matches a condition?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of integers and I need to find the sum of its items. If the list contains any `null` items, the result should be `null`. My current implementation:

```
intList.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull) ? null : intList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Can this be done with a single continuous stream? Is there an operation that terminates the stream if an item meets a condition?

Comment: Can this have negative numbers also? Or only positive?

Comment: Does this help? [How to Break from Java Stream forEach](https://www.baeldung.com/java-break-stream-foreach)

Comment: Any reason why it has to be done with a stream?  A simple loop and break seems more obvious.

Comment: @user16632363 The inside logic is more complex, than this simplified version, so I would prefer to use a stream as I find it more readable.

Comment: @Abra your link is really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your question "Is there an operation that terminates the stream if an item meets a condition?", Java 9 introduces [`Stream::takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) which does this.

However, using this for your use case would result in a sum of everything before the null (not what you are expecting of actually returning a null). For your case, and being limited to the JDK, using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69450221/1709089) proposed by [M A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064245/m-a) is the best (though it does not stop when it reaches a null).

The actual best way would be if there is a `takeWhileInclusive` combined with the reduce operation. Unfortunately, `takeWhileInclusive` does not exist in the JDK. However, [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev), who is a committer in the JDK, has written a stream extension library ([StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)) which has [`StreamEx::takeWhileInclusive`](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.html#takeWhileInclusive(java.util.function.Predicate)). It might be useful.

The following example, using that library, would step out with a null if null is encountered, or with the sum if it is not:

```java
StreamEx.of(intList).takeWhileInclusive(Objects::nonNull)
    .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a == null || b == null ? null : a + b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control how the sum reduction occurs:

```
Integer sum = intList.stream().reduce(0, (i1, i2) -> {
        if(i1 == null) return null;
        if(i2 == null) return null;
        return i1 + i2;
    });
```

Comment: Solution is really good. But just one thing, will this code allow stepping out if null encountered? I think it will go till the end and he needs to step out after first encounter of null.

Answer (score 2):

May be using reduce like:

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,null,4);
Integer sum = intList.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a == null || b == null ? null: a + b);
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Solution is really good. But just one thing, will this code allow stepping out if null encountered? I think it will go till the end and he needs to step out after first encounter of null.

Comment: Will iterate through the whole list.

Comment: So probably not a solution to given problem.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are not always the right solution.  And even when they are they may not be as efficient as a simple loop solution.  In your case, I would do the following:

```
public static Integer sum(List<Integer> vals) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer v : vals) {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        sum += v;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This both sums the elements or short circuits and returns a null.